# Uncaught TypeError: search is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

We have checked out quite a few posts on this, but none of them have seen to answered our issue. Our code is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- reference to Javascript here -->
    <script>
        function search(){

        }
        function focus(){
            document.getElementById("advSearchOptions").focus();
        }
    </script>
</head>


<!-- reference to HTML here -->
<body>
<!-- div for basic search bar -->
<div id="basicSearchBar">
    <form>
        <input id="basicSearchText" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search">
        <input id="basicSearchButton" type="submit" value="" onclick=search() />
    </form>
</div>
<!-- div for advanced searching -->
<div id="advSearchBar">
    <div id="advSearchOptions">
        <!-- Education Form -->
        <form id="advFormEducation">
            <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search">
        </form>
        <!-- Skill Form -->
        <form id="advFormSkill">
            <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search">
        </form>
        <!-- Work Form -->
        <form id="advFormWork">
            <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search">
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- Adv Search Button -->
    <p id='advButtonStyle'><button id="advSearchButton" type="menuexpand" value="" onclick=focus()></button></p>
</div>
<!-- div for search results -->
<div id="searchResults">
</div>
</body>
<footer>
    {% endblock %}
</footer>
</html>
```

The two issues we are having are: 1. When clicking on the first button

```
<input id="basicSearchButton" type="submit" value="" onclick=search() />
```

The console gives us an Uncaught TypeError: search is not a function error code. We would like to understand what we may be doing wrong that is causing this error to appear.

.2. When clicking on the second button

```
<p id='advButtonStyle'><button id="advSearchButton" type="menuexpand" value="" onclick=focus()></button></p>
```

The console does not give an error, however no call or code is executed from the focus function in our javascript.

We have left out the CSS, but if anyone can help that would be greatly appreciated.

We have tried fixes including : scope/placement and renaming

Comment: You can start by wrapping the function calls between quotes.

Comment: That had no effect on our errors, but thank you! We've wrapped them now.

Comment: What happens if you move the script tag to the bottom of the body tag?

Comment: @GerritLuimstra — Nothing. That would only make a difference if the script was trying to immediately read the DOM. It isn't, it just defines functions.

Comment: No change on our errors.

Comment: Alright, what happens. Is that you submit the form. Which will refresh the page if you don't give the action tag. Change your buttons to input[type=button] might fix this.

Comment: Sadly still the same.

Comment: Alright, the code itself is not wrong, as demonstrated here: https://jsfiddle.net/1gtnLaad/

Comment: I have not found a solution, but I have found what is causing this error. If you remove the form around the buttons, it works.

Comment: I have found the solution. The search function seems to be a reserved form function. Changing it to for example test12() will solve this problem.

Comment: Interesting. Also Quentin, that question that you marked us as a duplicate of does not answer this question.

Comment: YES, thank you Gerrit!

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped!

Comment: As a final addition.. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp

Comment: @GerritLuimstra that solve our problem. Thanks a lot.